Is there any way to disable drag gestures of user in BottomSheet on Compose?
I have webView in a BottomSheet.But when user starts to scroll website also bottomSheet starting to      dragging.I dont want this.I wants, just when user holds and starts to drag dragHandle , bottomsheet can      draggable
 ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = {
            scope.launch {
                isExpanded.hide()
            }
        },
        dragHandle = null,
        containerColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
        sheetState = sheetState,
        modifier = Modifier
            .systemBarsPadding()
     ) {
       AndroidView(factory = { context ->
                    WebView(context).apply {
                        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                        settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
                        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                        settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
                        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                        )
                        webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                        if (webURL != null) {
                            loadUrl(webURL)
                        }
                    }
              })
     }

I tried ;
confirmValueChange = { false }
pointerInput(Unit){ ... }

They didn't worked.
